# Opencart 3.0.3.7 event not catch, not working

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-events

Note: I had read tons of information here and another sources, including official docs.

I have a payment extension - ex title simplepay.

1. I want to know specifically if it is a way to "listen" to a system (predefined) event.
2. I want to run some logic when an order status has changed.

In the `admin/controller/extension/payment/simplepay.php` I have this (nothing more elsewhere):

```php
    public function install()
    {
        $this->load->model('setting/event');

        /** addEvent($code, $trigger, $action, $status = 1, $sort_order = 0); */
        $this->model_setting_event->addEvent(
            'do_transaction_on_order_status_change',
            'catalog/controller/api/order/history/after',
            'extension/payment/simplepay/doTransactionOnOrderStatusChange');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        $this->load->model('setting/event');
        /** deleteEventByCode($code); */
        $this->model_setting_event->deleteEventByCode('do_transaction_on_order_status_change');
    }

    public function doTransactionOnOrderStatusChange(&$route, &$data)
    {
        // testing purpose for the moment
        $log = new Log('aaaaaa.log');
        $log->write('Route   ' . $route);
    }
```

The event `do_transaction_on_order_status_change` is properly registered in events list.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!

After a while I got the point.

My method `doTransactionOnOrderStatusChange(&$route, &$data)` was writted with 3 parameters.

Like `doTransactionOnOrderStatusChange(&$route, &$data, &$output)`.

The problem is that OC 3+ not accept a third parameter, even if there is a "before" or an "after" event.

<s>And another problem was the related event: it must be `admin/controller/sale/order/history/before`. (or /after)</s>

No other event on order change worked. (probably this event is the only admin event, the rest being from catalog).

---

**Later edit**

The above works only for trigger the method, but had nonsense to do what was supposed to.

So, after other research time, it was obvious that the event I need to listen to was: `catalog/controller/api/order/history/after`. (an event raised from admin, but from catalog, weird!!).

To listen to that event, was need to make another controller in `catalog/controller/extension/payment/simplepay.php` then put that method (`doTransactionOnOrderStatusChange`) inside it.

Note that my question contains the proper event.

I hope someone will find this helpful!